# asp.net core form does postback instead of ajax call on success

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following

`<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddEvent" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="onSubmitEventSuccess">`

which generates 
`<form data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="onSubmitEventSuccess" action="/Home/AddEvent" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">`

and I have both the the validation scripts added

`<script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>`

When submitted, it goes through but browser navigates to /Home/AddEvent instead of provide an ajax call which onSuccess never fires.

I think I have everything wired up properly, not sure what I am missing.

Here is the code for the server-side

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddEvent(SubmitEventModel model)
{
     return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include files from Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax package to fix this problem. You can download it from https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/tree/master/dist. If you are using bower you can install it with name "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive"